# TypeScript complains on my setState statement that is using property accessors

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the code example below, where I try to have one onInputChange handler for several inputs, TypeScript gives me the following error on the statement `{[name]: value}`:

```
[ts]
Argument of type '{ [x: number]: string | boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SoftwareLicenseCodesState | ((prevState: Readonly<SoftwareLicenseCodesState>, props: Readonly<SoftwareLicenseCodesProps>) => SoftwareLicenseCodesState | Pick<SoftwareLicenseCodesState, "count" | ... 4 more ... | "distributor"> | null) | Pick<...> | null'.
  Type '{ [x: number]: string | boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<SoftwareLicenseCodesState, "count" | "oneTimeUsage" | "duration" | "validFrom" | "validTo" | "distributor">'.
    Property 'count' is missing in type '{ [x: number]: string | boolean; }'.
```

What is wrong here? How can I fix it?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './SoftwareLicenseCodes.css';

interface SoftwareLicenseCodesProps {
}

interface SoftwareLicenseCodesState {
    count: string;
    oneTimeUsage: boolean;
    duration: string;
    validFrom: string;
    validTo: string;
    distributor: string;
}

class SoftwareLicenseCodes extends React.Component<SoftwareLicenseCodesProps, SoftwareLicenseCodesState> {
    constructor(props: SoftwareLicenseCodesProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            distributor: '',
            count:'',
            oneTimeUsage: false,
            duration: '',
            validFrom: '',
            validTo: ''
        };

        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        alert('submit');
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    onInputChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const value = event.currentTarget.type === 'checkbox' ? event.currentTarget.checked : event.currentTarget.value;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="user-container software-codes">
                <div className="user-single-container">
                    <h1>Software License Codes</h1>

                    <form className="software-codes__form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <label>
                            <span className="software-codes__input-element">Count</span>
                            <input
                                name="count"
                                type="number"
                                value={this.state.count}
                            />
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <span className="software-codes__input-element">Distributor</span>
                            <input
                                name="distributor"
                                type="text"
                                value={this.state.distributor}
                            />
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <span className="software-codes__input-element">One time usage</span>
                            <input
                                name="oneTimeUsage"
                                type="checkbox"
                                checked={this.state.oneTimeUsage}
                            />
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <span className="software-codes__input-element">Duration</span>
                            <input
                                name="duration"
                                type="number"
                                value={this.state.duration}
                            />
                        </label>
                        <input className="software-codes__input-element" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SoftwareLicenseCodes;
```

Comment: You didn't include the code for your `this.setState()`, but It looks like you are passing an object to `this.setState()` that is different from the type of object it expects to receive.

Comment: @FrankFajardo - It's in the `onInputChange` callback: `this.setState({[name]: value});`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I have edited the post.

Comment: @user1283776 - I've updated my answer from last year with a **much** better second option. :-) (Side note: As far as I can tell, `name` is undefined in `onInputChange`. I think you meant `event.currentTarget.name`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown the interfaces the errors complain about (`LicenseCodesState`, `Pick`), but I'm going to assume they're defined similarly to your quoted `SoftwareLicenseCodesState`.

To allow dynamic property assignment like your `this.setState({[name]: value});`, you need to do one of two things:

1. Add dynamic property access to the definition (but keep reading):

   ```
   interface SoftwareLicenseCodesState {
       count: string;
       oneTimeUsage: boolean;
       duration: string;
       validFrom: string;
       validTo: string;
       distributor: string;
       [key: string]: any;            // <===
   }
   ```

   The handbook calls this a "string index signature," it's covered under [Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).

   The problem with this is that, of course, that means you lose type checking — not just where you use it, but basically anywhere you use `SoftwareLicenseCodesState`.
2. Use a type assertion where you do the `setState` call. You have a couple of options there. You can use an assertion on `name`:

   ```
   const name = event.currentTarget.name as keyof SoftwareLicenseCodesState;
   this.setState({[name]: value});
   ```

   or on the state object you're passing:

   ```
   this.setState({[event.currentTarget.name]: value} as Partial<SoftwareLicenseCodesState>);
   ```

   This loses type checking on that call, but preserves it elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I updated my post again. Awesome, thanks for the solution! If you don't mind my asking, where do I learn these things? I have read the TypeScript handbook (on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html), but still find myself stumbling often.

Comment: @user1283776 - So do I. :-) For some reason, I just don't get on with the TypeScript handbook/documentation. This one I learned about a while back from a different SO question. Sorry not to have a better answer on that for you.

Comment: Thank you anyway! :-) If you have time and energy, consider looking at my follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144901/typescript-failed-to-compile-because-type-declaration-of-any-loses-type-safety :-)

Comment: It's actually seems like the same question here .

Comment: Losing the type checking is quite a big deal. Why use Typescript then?

Comment: @Remi - Sadly, when dealing with certain kinds of code (like this code getting the name of the property dynamically as a string), compromises have to be made. But there's a **much** better compromise to make above, which I've added. :-)

Comment: Ah brilliant. I misread that. I've used it in a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003993/typescript-generic-state-change-function-type-casting-error

Comment: @Remi - I'm not sure you did misread it, I edited. :-D Happy coding!