# Typescript generic state change function type casting error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-state

I'm creating a generic function to change the state.

The error message:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '() => { [x:string]: string }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IUserSignUpState | Pick<IUserSignUpState, "url" | "errors"> | ((prevState: Readonly<IUserSignUpState>, props: Readonly<IUserSignUpState>) => IUserSignUpState | Pick<...> | null) null'.

Type '() => { [x: string] string; }' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Readonly<IUserSignUpState>, props: Readonly<IUserSignUpState>) => IUserSignupState | Pick<IUserSignUpState>, "url" | "errors" | null'. 

Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IUserSignUpState | Pick<IUserSignUpState, "url" | "errors"> | null'.

Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<IUserSignUpState, "url" | "errors">': url, errors.
```

This is the example of the generic change function:

**./UserSignUp.tsx**

```js
interface IUserSignUpState {
  url: string;
  errors: string[];
  // following can be used, but will lose type checking (*)
  // [key: string]: string;
}

class UserSignUp extends React.Component<{}, IUserSignUpState>
  state = {
    url: '',
    name: '',
    errors: [],
  };

  render() {
    const { url, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="url" value={url} onChange={this.change} />
        <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.change} />
      <form>
    )
  }

  change = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;

    // gives error here:
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        [name]: value
      }
    })
  }
};
```

In this example the change event should only be allowed to update `url: string;` and `name: string;`, and not `errors: []`.

Should I be defining the 'url' and 'name' types and reuse that in the change function somehow?

---

*In the Typescript documentation it states that [Indexable types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) can be used. However, by doing so I will lose type checking. And a side-effect is that I could potentially also set the 'error' state, which typically shouldn't be possible from the change function.

---

update: based on the answer in this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144584/typescript-complains-on-my-setstate-statement-that-is-using-property-accessors/52144801?noredirect=1#comment100541684_52144801), the following solution is possible:

split up the interface:

```
interface IInputState {
  url: string;
}

interface IUserSignUpState extends IInputState {
  errors: string[];
}
```

And re-use that interface, by either:

```
this.setState({ [name]: value } as Partial<IInputStates>)
```

or:

```
const name = event.target.name as keyof IInputStates;
const value = event.target.value;

this.setState(():IInputStates => {
  return { [name]: value }
});
```

Comment: When does the error occurs?

Comment: The IDE throws the Typescript error instantly. Also resulting that React will render in error mode

Answer (score 1):

Using types won't prevent the errors property from being changed as the type checking applies at compile time only. This will still run as plain old dynamic JavaScript when it gets to the browser where anything goes.

If you want to restrict the properties the change function acts on you need to check the property name e.g. against an array of allowed values.

As a side note your inputs are missing the `name` property.

```js
 render() {
    const { url, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="url" value={url} onChange={this.change} />
        <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.change} />
      <form>
    )
  }

  change = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;

    if (!isValidProperty(name)) return;

    this.setState({ [name]: value } as Partial<IInputStates>)
  }

  // Dummy instance to force a compile warning and ensure we capture all the property names
  const inputExample: IInputStates = { url: '' };
  const inputKeys = Object.keys(inputExample);

  function isValidProperty(name: string): name is keyof IInputStates {
    return inputKeys.includes(name);
  }
```

Comment: Ah good thinkin'. That is definitely a good addition. It might be able to extract the 'name' | 'url' also via typescript (keyof) as well to get it dry. Let me check.

Comment: Yes, that works. `...name is ('name' | 'url')...` can be replaced by defining the keys: `type inputStateKeys = keyof IInputStates;` and then `...name is (inputStateKeys)...`. Now only remaining are the types keys as a value.  (`return ['name', 'url']`)

Comment: @Remi Good point - have updated the answer to make better use of the types.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions:

```
 this.setState<never>({ [name]: value } as Partial<IInputStates>)
```

Or

```
 this.setState({ [name]: value } as Pick<IInputStates, keyof IInputStates>);
```

There is an open issue in git, take a look:
[cannot setState with dynamic key name type-safe](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635)

Comment: i think the solution to use `never` is just a workaround since it skips checking types so it should be discouraged. Also, I think you can just do `this.setState<never>({ [name]: value })`