# i can't setState with dynamic key name in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I defined state interface of React component as following.

```
interface IState {
    email: string,
    password: string,
    errors: object
}
```

and in text input change event I am trying to set state with dynamic key as below.

```
handleInputChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {

        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }
```

However VSCode shows me this error

```
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IState | ((prevState: Readonly<IState>, props: Readonly<{}>) => IState | Pick<IState, "email" | "password" | "errors"> | null) | Pick<IState, "email" | "password" | "errors"> | null'.
  Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<IState, "email" | "password" | "errors">': email, password, errorsts(2345)
```

Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that `e.target.name` should be key of `IState` and `e.target.value` should be relative type from key in `IState`, to fix it you can manually cast type like

```
this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    } as Pick<IState, keyof IState>);
```

but it disables typescript for this function also you can cast it to any type, but it's unsafe.

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003993/typescript-generic-state-change-function-type-casting-error) answer also can be helpful for you

The best option is to use `ReduxForm`

Comment: this works, but I had to first cast it as `unknown` before casting to `Pick<State, keyof State>` (i.e., `this.setState({[name]: value} as unknown as Pick<State, keyof State>);`)

Answer (score 0):

We can also do something like this:

```
  const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const name = e.target.name as keyof typeof this.state;

    this.setState({ ...this.state, [name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

Comment: You should never use ...this.state dirrectly in this.setState like this, since you cannot be sure that this.state is actually the most up to date. Instead you need to use the variant of this.setState that takes an update function as argument: this.setState((state, props) => ({
  ...state, [name]: e.target.value }));

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
this.setState({ [field]: value } as unknown as Pick<IState, keyof IState>);
```